# How to get current program from time ranges

Tags: javascript, momentjs, angular, angular-moment

Let's say that i have a JSON file like this

```
[
    {
        "programId": "bla-bla-1",
        "programTitle": "bla bla 1",
        "programImg": "bla1.jpg",
        "startsAt": "Apr 05 2017 11:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)",
        "endsAt": "Apr 05 2017 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)"
    },
    {
        "programId": "bla-bla-2",
        "programTitle": "bla bla 2",
        "programImg": "bla2.jpg",
        "startsAt": "Apr 05 2017 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)",
        "endsAt": "Apr 05 2017 14:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)"
    },
    {
        "programId": "bla-bla-3",
        "programTitle": "bla bla 3",
        "programImg": "bla3.jpg",
        "startsAt": "Apr 05 2017 14:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)",
        "endsAt": "Apr 05 2017 16:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)"
    }
]
```

And current time is (Apr 05 2017 ***12:30:00*** GMT+0200 (EET)) how can i get the current program from those time ranges using Javascript also i can use library like momentJS

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Rajesh i tried MomentJS but can figure out how that can be possible ...

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @Rajesh do i have to make a loop and Query with MomentJS's isBetween() https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/ !

Comment: Yes you can do that. Use a loop and on valid match, push it to array if you have multiple programs and if only one then, set it to variable and break the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
var obj = [ { "programId": "bla-bla-1", "programTitle": "bla bla 1", "programImg": "bla1.jpg", "startsAt": "Apr 05 2017 11:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)", "endsAt": "Apr 05 2017 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)" }, { "programId": "bla-bla-2", "programTitle": "bla bla 2", "programImg": "bla2.jpg", "startsAt": "Apr 05 2017 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)", "endsAt": "Apr 05 2017 14:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)" }, {"programId": "bla-bla-3", "programTitle": "bla bla 3", "programImg": "bla3.jpg", "startsAt": "Apr 05 2017 14:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)", "endsAt": "Apr 05 2017 16:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)"}];

var now = new Date("Apr 05 2017 12:30:00 GMT+0200 (EET)").getTime();//new Date().getTime();

var prog = obj.find(o => {
  return (now >= new Date(o.startsAt).getTime() && now <= new Date(o.endsAt).getTime());
});

console.log(prog);
```

Comment: Though I don't have right, I'd like to request you to delete the answer as OP is yet to show code. Even I have an answer ready, but lets wait till OP shows his code.

Comment: @Rajesh i don't have a ready code, I posted a question Titus posted the answer and it worked :) ...

Comment: @dyaa the reason i requested Titus to remove answer and you to post your code is because that way we could help you with more than just answer. Now you have a working code but do you know, how it works? It's pros and cons? Trying on your own would hello you learn

Answer (score 1):

Note that the solution given by Tisus may not work on every browser since date parsing of non-standard string is system-dependent.

I suggest to parse your input using [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) instead of `new Date(String)`. Then you can use moment [`isBetween`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/) to check if the current day is in the given range.

Here a live sample:

```js
var input = [
    {
        "programId": "bla-bla-1",
        "programTitle": "bla bla 1",
        "programImg": "bla1.jpg",
        "startsAt": "Apr 05 2017 11:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)",
        "endsAt": "Apr 05 2017 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)"
    },
    {
        "programId": "bla-bla-2",
        "programTitle": "bla bla 2",
        "programImg": "bla2.jpg",
        "startsAt": "Apr 05 2017 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)",
        "endsAt": "Apr 05 2017 14:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)"
    },
    {
        "programId": "bla-bla-3",
        "programTitle": "bla bla 3",
        "programImg": "bla3.jpg",
        "startsAt": "Apr 05 2017 14:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)",
        "endsAt": "Apr 05 2017 16:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)"
    }
]

var prog = input.find(item => {
  //var now = moment();
  // mocking current time in order to get always the same result
  var now = moment("Apr 05 2017 12:30:00 GMT+0200 (EET)", 'MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss Z')
  var start = moment(item.startsAt, 'MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss Z');
  var end = moment(item.endsAt, 'MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss Z');
  return now.isBetween(start, end);
});

console.log(prog);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

---

As side note: I agree with Rajesh, providing code attempt would help getting better answers and gives you the chance to learn better.

Comment: prog is undefined

Comment: You are getting `undefined` because current time is after `2017-04-05 16:00:00` that is the lastest time in your input. I've edited my snippet mocking current time to always get the same result.